# Tracking an app is being uninstalled before or after specific time using Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm having an issue now, I have an android app and its using Firebase Analytics, it has a tutorial when start, and I want to track people will uninstall my app after or before tutorial. I'm tried to add custom parameter
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPgqQ.png)

and tried to log an event with this code:

```
Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("app_remove", "first_tutorial", 1);
```

but it returns an error. I still don't know how to use parameter reporting right way.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `app_remove` should be logged automatically, you don't need to write code for it. What error do you get? Also: given that app removes are tracked (on Android at least) automatically, without this code, what's the problem?

Comment: I mean, I know app_remove is being logged automatically, but I want to track when people uninstall it, they finished tutorial or not.

Comment: To do that you should log your own event (e.g. `finished_tutorial`) and then compare the number of folks who have that event vs the number of have `app_remove`.

Comment: Alright thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `app_remove` event is logged automatically on Android. You don't need to write any code for it.

If you want to be able to analyze how many people completed the tutorial before uninstalling, you should log your own custom event (e.g. `finished_tutorial`) when the user finished the tutorial. Then you can compare the event counts in the dashboard, or do more complex [funnel analysis in BigQuery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxNrkjBeHpw).